# how to make same length for all variable?

Tags: r

I want to fit data in liner model but cannot be carry out because of different length. how to fix this problem

```
temp<-as.factor(c(rep(150,2),rep(160,2),rep(170,2)))
pressure<-as.factor(c(rep(200,6),rep(215,6),rep(230,6)))
obs<-c(90.4,90.2,90.1,90.3,90.5,90.7,90.7,90.6,90.5,90.6,90.8,90.9,90.2,90.4,89.9,90.1,90.4,90.1)
t1<-data.frame(temp,pressure,obs)

result<-lm(obs~pressure*temp)
```

in R give this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = obs ~ pressure * temp, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'temp')

because length of temp is 6 but for `obs` and `pressure` is 18.

Comment: When you look at the `t1` dataframe, is it correct? R automatically recycles the `temp` vector to match the length of the other vectors when creating the dataframe, have the right `temp` values been matched up with the other rows?

Comment: A linear regression is carried out on observations comprising a value for each of your variables (dependent and indepentent). So the point is not fixing a technical problem with R but to ensure that your data really is correct. If you end up with vectors of different length this means something is wrong with the data set and the solution must be to correct the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to specify the `data`

```
lm(obs~pressure*temp, t1)
#Call:
#lm(formula = obs ~ pressure * temp, data = t1)

#Coefficients:
#        (Intercept)          pressure215          pressure230              temp160              temp170  pressure215:temp160  pressure230:temp160  pressure215:temp170  
#          9.030e+01            3.500e-01           -7.479e-14           -1.000e-01            3.000e-01            8.194e-14           -2.000e-01           -1.000e-01  
#pressure230:temp170  
#         -3.500e-01
```

Otherwise, it is checking for the variables created  in the global environment which has less number of  elements.  When we created the `data.frame`, due to recycling the elements are  replicated to have the same length